# Google Chart Histogram - bucket element wider than bucketSize

Tags: json, charts, google-visualization, visualization

How do I display every bucket element while they conform neatly in their own bucket?

I have trouble displaying a histogram the way I want it. 
At the second picture bucket 1 and bucket 4 are filled with 1 element, but the elements are displayed beyond their own bucket (from 1 to 4, and from 4 to 6).

Is there an option property that I can use to force the elements to remain within their own buckets?

Right kind of way to display
[Right way to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gewsX.png)

Wrong kind of way to display
[Wrong way to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XZ4F.png)

Below is the options json that I present to the charts api, the only difference between the two charts are the block color and orientation. Neither influence the element size (tested).

```
  options_json = {
      "title": "Client Side Errors"
      ,"titlePosition": "none"
      ,"legend": { "position": "none" }
      ,"backgroundColor": background_color
      ,"chartArea": { "backgroundColor": chart_background_color, "width": "100%", "height": "100%" }
      ,"textColor": "white"
      ,"orientation": "vertical"
      ,"colors": [chart_colour]
      ,"vAxis": { "viewWindowMode": "pretty", "textColor": "transparent", "baselineColor": horizontal_gridline_color
      , "gridlines": { "color": horizontal_gridline_color, "label": "horizontalline" } }
      , "hAxis": { "ticks": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], "direction": chart_orientation, "viewWindowMode": "pretty"
      , "textColor": "transparent", "gridlines": { "max": 10, "color": vertical_gridline_color }
      , "baselineColor": vertical_gridline_color}
      , "histogram": { "bucketSize": 1, "minValue": 1, "maxValue": 6 }
      , "bar": {  }
    }
```

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data used to draw the chart?

Comment: The right one comes down to;

Comment: The wrong one comes down to; { v: 1, v: 'count a: 1'},{ v: 1, v: 'count a: 2'},{ v: 4, v: 'count a: 1'}
The right one comes down to; { v: 1, v: 'count a: 1'},{ v: 1, v: 'count a: 2'},{ v: 2, v: 'count a: 1'},{ v: 3, v: 'count a: 1'}

Where the first value determines the bucket for the element to be put in.